# Apache Spark could not deserialize `TopicPartition` on cluster

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I used `spark-sql-kafka-0-10` to read batch from kafka with Spark `2.4` and scala `2.11.12`. So my `build.sbt` file has following dependencies.

```
"org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-core" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-sql" % sparkVersion % "provided",
"org.apache.spark"  %% "spark-sql-kafka-0-10" % sparkVersion
```

I also used `sbt-assembly` plugin to make fat jar of my application. It works well when deploy this jar file on local spark as below where $FAT_JAR point my assembly file:

```
./spark-submit --class $MAIN_CLASS --master local --driver-class-path $FAT_JAR $FAT_JAR
```

But when I deploy it on cluster (even when both of worker and master are on same machine) it throw exception about deserialization problem of `TopicPartiton`.

How I run on cluster:

```
./spark-submit \
  --master spark://spark-master:7077 \
  --class $MAIN_CLASS \
  --driver-class-path $FAT_JAR \
  --packages org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.11:2.4.0 \
  $FAT_JAR
```

I've also tried `--jars` and I'm sure worker and master has the save version of `kafka-client` which is `2.0.0`

Exception log:

```
Caused by: java.io.InvalidClassException: org.apache.kafka.common.TopicPartition; class invalid for deserialization
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:169)
        at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.checkDeserialize(ObjectStreamClass.java:874)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2043)
```

Why spark fails to deserialize `TopicPartition` and how can I solve it?

Comment: Do you get this on the driver node or others? Are all of them using the same JVM (version)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution. 
Just as I set `SPARK_DIST_PATH` to `$(hadoop classpath)`, It included `kafka-client-0.8` which is differ from `kafka-client-2.0.0` that uses in `spark-sql-kafka-0-10`. 
I've just used hadoop indcluded version of spark and unset `SPARK_DIST_PATH` to resolve it.

Any way I expects that `spark.executor.userClassPathFirst` and `spark.driver.userClassPathFirst` help to solve this issue in general, but right now they are experimental.